# Spring Cloud Streams ignores parameters of producer

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm developing a simple service that is consuming messages from one Kafka topic and producing modified messages to another topic. The service works fine except settings paremeter "compression type" of the producer.

Parameter "compression: gzip" are ignored by SCS and set default values "none"
Regarding [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/kafka/kafka-binder/config-options.html) I should set

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.producer.compression.type
```

I've tried it

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          destination: in-topic
          binder: kafkaProd
          group: ms-pos-sales-mirror
        process-out-0:
          destination: out-topic
          binder: kafkaNewProd
          producer:
            compression: gzip
```

And tried this

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          destination: in-topic
          binder: kafkaProd
          group: ms-pos-sales-mirror
        process-out-0:
          destination: out-topic
          binder: kafkaNewProd
          producer:
            configuration:
              compression:
                type: gzip
```

The results were the same: both times compression type parameter was ignored.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: The example in doc is the exception.`To avoid repetition, Spring Cloud Stream supports setting values for all channels, in the format of spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.producer.<property>=<value>. `try this: spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.producer. compression =gzip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you are missing `kafka` part of the property:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          process-out-0:
            producer:
              compression-type: gzip
```